# Java thread output

Tags: java, multithreading, error-handling, operating-system

```
public class oneThread extends Thread {
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("geeks ");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }
        System.out.println("forgeeks ");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        oneThread c1 = new oneThread();
        oneThread c2 = new oneThread();
        c1.start();
        c2.start();
        System.out.println(c1.isAlive());
        System.out.println(c2.isAlive());
    }
}
```

its real output is ->

```
geeks 
true
true
geeks 
forgeeks 
forgeeks
```

how is this correct ?

I expected it to be ->

```
geeks 
geeks
true
true 
forgeeks 
forgeeks
```

Comment: Why should it not be correct?

Comment: Seems OK to me.  What don't you like about it?

Comment: @YatiSawhney - There are no guarantees if thread priorities are different either.  Read the javadocs!

Comment: @StephenC , I believe if the underlying os supports thread priorities. It will have an impact. After all they all(threads) get converted to system threads

Comment: There are no **guarantees**.  Not least because priorities at the system threads don't have guaranteed scheduling behavior either.  It is all "best effort" semantics, with a dollop of unfairness thrown in for good measure.  (Actually ... efficiency)  But don't just believe what I say.  Go and read the javadocs and see what they say.   (Your *belief* is of no consequence.  This is a matter of facts, not beliefs :-) )

Comment: Defne 'correct'.

Comment: No, don't define "correct".  That's the JLS's job.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem - EJP means that the OP should define what >>he<< thinks is correct behavior.

Comment: @StephenC really?  Thanks for the clarification!!

Comment: Oh ... I didn't notice smiley on your previous comment.  (Oh wait .... :-) )   The clarification if not for your benefit.  It is for the OP's benefit, since there is some doubt that he would "get" your humor.

Comment: @StephenC ... Many thanks!

Comment: @YatiSawhney, Java threads don't get "converted" to system threads, they _are_ system threads.

Comment: I thought it should be -> geeks

geeks

true

true

forgeeks

forgeeks

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem OK, *you* define 'correct', or cite it from the JLS, and tell us whether the OP's output departs from it, and, if so, how. Or, butt out. I don't mind which. NB I carefully didn't say 'define correct': I said 'define "correct"'. There is a difference.

Comment: Correct -> I meant to say does c2.start() is called after the thread1.alive and thread2.alive ?

Comment: I am very new to java ... So I have many doubts !!

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of legal execution sequences that could give rise to that output.

For example:

1. in main: c1.start()
2. in main: c2.start()
3. in thread 1: println("geeks")
4. in thread 1: sleep
5. in main: println(c1.isAlive()); println(c2.isAlive());
6. in thread 2: println("geeks")
7. in thread 2: sleep
8. in thread 1: println("for geeks")
9. in thread 2: println("for geeks")
10. JVM terminates since all threads have completed

Other possible execution sequences include:

- Steps 3 and 4 could happen before step 2.
- Thread 2 could be scheduled before thread 1.
- Thread 2 could "overtake" thread 1 due to the sleep times being imprecise.

And so on.

These are all *legal* behaviors, and on some platforms you might actually encounter them.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly valid behavior. The JVM is free to decide which Thread runs and when. Some of the things you should note is that starting a thread takes some time, and while Thread 2 is still starting, main keeps going and gets to its print. Also Threads can be put to sleep for a lengthy IO operation such as System.out.println, and another thread will run while the print is executing.

Comment: But when thread 1 prints geeks and goes to sleep , c2.start() starts. Now , c2 should print geeks and go to sleep ?  Then main executes c1.isalive and c2.isalive ??

Comment: It's a simple race between main and thread 2. There is no guarantee that the new started thread will get running time from the JVM before main.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I understood .